# How do i render a image from my active camera when i have a sequence with an animation?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, output

Hi there I already did some projects in Blender but now I am stuck.
I always rendered still images out of blender, now I started to make a small product animation which I also could render as images and make a composition.

My problem now is that if I want to render a still image but from another camera (selected as active) it always renders me the frame I am on in the sequence.

[image: the render i got]

Would really help me to finish the project.

I attached some pictures so you see whats my still image that I want from camera 1 and what the output is from the sequence.
[image: the render i want]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly. You want to render a still image, but from a different frame as the one you are currently at? Why don't you just simply go to the frame you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah that would work but only if i have the frame in the camera. Problem is i want to render a still image from another camera, that is not in the sequence.

Comment: Got it working! i just did it like you said and put my ew camera with the frame i want in the sequence. that did the trick ;) thanks!